# retrieving list of files from SFTP server in java

Tags: java, ftp, sftp

I want the list of files of a particular directory which is present in sftp server or ftp server.I written following code to do that but it is not working for me.

```
  FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

    try {
        client.connect("ftp.secureftp-test.com ");
        client.login("test", "test");

        String[] names = client.listNames();
        for (String name : names) {
            System.out.println("Name = " + name);
        }

        FTPFile[] ftpFiles = client.listFiles();
        for (FTPFile ftpFile : ftpFiles) {
            // Check if FTPFile is a regular file
            if (ftpFile.getType() == FTPFile.FILE_TYPE) {
                System.out.println("FTPFile: " + ftpFile.getName() + "; " + FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(ftpFile.getSize()));
            }
        }
        client.logout();
        client.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I replace the jar of jsse but now above code is not giving any output.It does not returning any file name.

So anybody knows how to get the list of all files from ftp or sftp server using java and only opensource libraries.

Comment: javax.net.SocketFactory seems to be a part of java SE since version 1.4. What version of java are you using?

Comment: I am using java 1.6 so dont think that this is the problem.

Comment: Please post your classpath, and/or the command line you use to execute this.  Even though you've added that JAR, you're either misspelling it or something else is wrong there; it's still not quite in the classpath, I don't think.

Comment: As Dean said, print System.getProperty("java.class.path") from within the program and verify that the path to the jsse.jar file is in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know which protocol your server is actually using?

You didn't specify what library you were using, but it looks like commons-net.  I see that commons-net does have an FTPSClient class, but that is for [FTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS), not SFTP.

Assuming you're talking about SFTP, I use the library [JSCH](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch).

Comment: Thank you The Elite Gentleman, but I also made a mistake in the JSCH site.  Please change the link to http://www.jcraft.com/jsch

Comment: Thanks guys, but anyone know public ftps and sftp test server other than chilka so that I can test the things.

Comment: If you are using windows, try using FileZilla server for FTPS.  I don't know what other servers are available.

You can test SFTP using most openssh servers if you have shell access.

http://filezilla-project.org/

Answer (score 1):

Hi to retrieve files from ftp server I got another very powerful library which I like to share with all of you.The name of that library is edtftpj.jar Which is open source and we can easily upload and download files,we can list files and folders from particular directory of remote server.I found it very powerful. You can download it from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/CatalogJar.htm)

Comment: edtFTPj/PRO is a commercial extension of edtFTPj that supports SFTP: see http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpjssl/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set your `CLASSPATH` to your JDK lib. `javax.net.SocketFactory` is standard in Java JDK.

Comment: Try compiling and runing using `javac/java -cp <classpath of libs here>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSch Open Source API. Using this API you can list all files/directories from SFTP server - I also found a working example which shows how to list files from SFTP - 
http://kodehelp.com/get-list-files-sftp-server-java/